# Error: permission denied while mysql_intstall_db

Tags: mariadb, lxc, alpine-linux

I tried to install mariadb on blank Alpine Linux 3.6 in LXC container hosted on Turris OS (OpenWrt omnia 15.05 r47055).

Installation failed on permision denied error. I change privilegs but instalataror still failure.

```
root@alpinelxccontainer:~# DB_DATA_PATH="/var/lib/mysql"
root@alpinelxccontainer:~# DB_ROOT_PASS="heslo"
root@alpinelxccontainer:~# DB_USER="mariadb_user"
root@alpinelxccontainer:~# DB_PASS="heslo"
root@alpinelxccontainer:~# MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET="200M"

root@alpinelxccontainer:~# mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=${DB_DATA_PATH}

WARNING: The host 'alpinelxccontainer' could not be looked up with /usr/bin/resolveip.
This probably means that your libc libraries are not 100 % compatible
with this binary MariaDB version. The MariaDB daemon, mysqld, should work
normally with the exception that host name resolving will not work.
This means that you should use IP addresses instead of hostnames
when specifying MariaDB privileges !
Installing MariaDB/MySQL system tables in '/var/lib/mysql' ...
2018-07-25 22:14:30 3069281488 [Note] /usr/bin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.32-MariaDB) starting as process 1876 ...
2018-07-25 22:14:30 3069281488 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
2018-07-25 22:14:30 3069281488 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Can't create file' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control'
2018-07-25 22:14:30 3069281488 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2018-07-25 22:14:30 3069281488 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-07-25 22:14:30 3069281488 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2018-07-25 22:14:30 3069281488 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-07-25 22:14:30 3069281488 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-07-25 22:14:30 3069281488 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-07-25 22:14:30 3069281488 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-07-25 22:14:30 3069281488 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2018-07-25 22:14:30 3069281488 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-07-25 22:14:30 3069281488 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2018-07-25 22:14:30 3069281488 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ibXXXXXX' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
2018-07-25 22:14:30 b6f184d0  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
2018-07-25 22:14:30 3069281488 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-07-25 22:14:30 3069281488 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-07-25 22:14:30 3069281488 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2018-07-25 22:14:30 3069281488 [ERROR] Aborting


root@alpinelxccontainer:~# ls -la /var/lib/mysql/
total 0
drwxr-sr-x    1 mysql    mysql           48 Jul 25 22:14 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            36 Jul 25 22:09 ..
drwx------    1 mysql    mysql            0 Jul 25 22:14 mysql
-rw-rw----    1 mysql    mysql            0 Jul 25 22:14 mysql-bin.index
drwx------    1 mysql    mysql            0 Jul 25 22:14 test



root@alpinelxccontainer:~# chmod -R 777 /var/lib/mysql/
root@alpinelxccontainer:~# ls -la /var/lib/mysql/
total 0
drwxrwxrwx    1 mysql    mysql           48 Jul 25 22:14 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            36 Jul 25 22:09 ..
drwxrwxrwx    1 mysql    mysql            0 Jul 25 22:14 mysql
-rwxrwxrwx    1 mysql    mysql            0 Jul 25 22:14 mysql-bin.index
drwxrwxrwx    1 mysql    mysql            0 Jul 25 22:14 test


root@alpinelxccontainer:~# mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=${DB_DATA_PATH}
Still same error: [ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
```

Complete dump of installation: https://gist.github.com/jakubs/24c642bc8d6779beaf1b944c6f399675
Related: installation guide: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/MariaDB

Comment: is it possible that there is selinux or apparmor in effect? Or somehow /var/lib/mysql is readonly within the container?

Comment: This is weird, especially the warning about `resolveip`. How exactly did you create this container? What LXC version and how does your container's `config` look?